# Can I show/hide a view model element with data annotations based on a condition?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, data-annotations

I am generating a lot of views using data annotations and a few custom templates.

```
public class Container
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    [RequiredForRole("Editor"), StringLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Short Name")]
    [RequiredForRole("Editor"), StringLength(10)]      
    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Maximum Elements Allowed")]
    [RequiredForRole("Admin")]
    public int MaxSize { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Components")]
    public IList<Component> Components{ get; set; }
}
```

In the views, I just use `@Html.DisplayForModel()`, `@Html.EditorForModel`, etc.

Certain properties need to be editable by users in some roles but hidden for others. As you can see, I've implemented a custom validation attribute `RequiredForRole` which checks a value exists but only if the current user has a certain role.

I really need a custom Display attribute, but as `DisplayAttribute` is sealed, this doesn't seem possible.

I want to avoid having lots of different templates for different kinds of users, or start pushing this logic of who sees what down onto the views. What's the neatest way to solve this problem?

Comment: In your custom templates, you use DisplayFor or EditorFor helpers ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Yes but I don't have a custom template for many model types - they just use the standard 'generated' templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, maybe. The (BIG) problem is : how to check the current user's role...

```
public class VisibleForRoleAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
    {
        public string[]  Roles { get; set; }
        public VisibleForUserAttribute(string[] roles)
        {
            Roles = roles;
        }
        public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
        {
            var toShow =  Roles.Any(IsUserInRole);
            metadata.ShowForDisplay = metadata.ShowForEdit =  toShow; // or just ShowForEdit

        }
        private bool IsUserInRole(string roleName)
        {
            return HttpContext.Current != null &&
                   HttpContext.Current.User != null &&
                   HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(roleName); //if you use MembershipProvider
        }
    }
```

usage

```
[VisibleForRole(new[]{"Administrator", "Editor"})]
```

Comment: I've never seen `IMetadataAware` before. This will be very useful. Thanks very much, Raphaël!